# Writing repeating words in a line in a textfile to another textfile

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function where it reads a textfile and it inputs the repeated words once in another textfile. The problem is that this code just gives the last line repeated words.

```
import string 

 def repeat_words(in_file, out_file):
     file_in = open(in_file, "r")
     file_out = open(out_file, "w")
     for lines in file_in:
     words = lines.lower().split()
     seen_words = []
     repeat_words = [] 
        for word in words:
            word = word.strip(string.punctuation)
            if word in seen_words and word not in repeat_words:
                repeat_words.append(word)
            seen_words.append(word)
   
 file_out.write(' '.join(repeat_words) + '\n')
 file_in.close()
 file_out.close()

inF = "nnn.txt"
OutF = "Untitled-1.txt"
repeat_words(inF, OutF)
```

Comment: writing repeated words to the file needs to happen *within* the for-loop

Comment: Your indentation for `file_out.write(' '.join(repeat_words) + '\n')` seems a bit off...?

Comment: The shown code wouldn't even run (bad indentation).

Comment: Is it safe to assign a value to a variable named `word` when that identifier is the variable used in the for loop? It doesn’t seem OK to me.

Comment: Using `repeat_words` both for the function name and a list in this function is strange. I’ll be surprised Python permits that (but I did not write Python code for a long time…)

Comment: Indentation in Python is meaningful. Submitting code with indentation errors is like submitting code with spelling errors in function names or keywords. Make sure that the code you share is indented in the way you think it should be. In this case, the obvious problem is the indentation of the 3 `file_ ..` lines, but it's perhaps less obvious due to the indentation mess around it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make function where it reads a textfile and it inputs the repeated words once in another textfile.

Your code is a little unclear.

If you want to pick up repeated words from fileA and write them to fileB, try below code.

```py
import string 

def repeat_words(in_file, out_file):
    with open(in_file, "r") as file_in, open(out_file, "w") as file_out :
        seen_words = set()
        repeated_words = []
        for line in file_in.readlines():
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                word = word.lower().strip(string.punctuation)
                if word in seen_words and word not in repeat_words:
                    repeated_words.append(word)
                seen_words.add(word)
                
        file_out.write(' '.join(repeat_words))


inF = "nnn.txt"
OutF = "Untitled-1.txt"
repeat_words(inF, OutF)
```